# How to power above $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: math-mode

I'd like to ask if there is any possibility to power `$\mathbb{F}_p`$ directly above the `p`.

I mean typing `$\mathbb{F}^*_p^{k}$` comes out that the power `k` is moved on the left not on the `k`, and I would like to have it directly above `k` like the star directly above the `$\mathbb{F}$`.

---

I would like to have something like this:

[image]

Comment: It is also not clear to me what you mean. The example you provided (`$\mathbb{F}^*_p^{k}$`) fails to compile. Perhaps `$\mathbb{F}^{*}_{p^{k}}$` accomplishes what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435460/how-to-power-above-mathbbf-p#comment1091955_435460), it appears that the below is sufficient:

```
$\mathbb{F}^{*}_{p^{k}}$
```

Depending upon the application, you might also wish to consider a star instead of an asterisk:

```
$\mathbb{F}^{\star}_{p^{k}}$
```

I provide an example of these on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/ynsndvrrsjhz).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the code you are seeking.

```
$\mathbb{F}^*_{p^k}$
```

[image]